# Div moves on hover with scale

Tags: css, html, positioning, transform, scale

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLaVb/1/

The caption that is positioned via position:absolute over the thumbnail (position:relative) moves when you hover over the thumbnail.. The only thing defined on :hover is the

```
transform:scale(1.2);
```

Any ideas how to fix?

I need two separate divs for the caption, 1 for the bg, 1 for the text (can't use RGBA).

Note that the margin around the image needs to remain. In this example, 5px, but could just as well be 20px or more.

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the working html +css

```
<a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/Darryl.Wilson1/MyPictures02#5157833312913845474"       style="padding:0px;margin:0px" class="thumbnail zoom">

<div class="container" style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
     <img src="http://lh6.ggpht.com/-iMWjZc44UuA/R5ROEhrn7OI/AAAAAAAAAV4/3l2mDuaeQ4Q/s160-c/Acura%252520Advanced%252520Sports%252520Car%252520Concept%25252002.jpg" style="width: 160px;">

    <div class="title_grid inside" style="width: 160px;margin:0px;position:absolute;left:0px ">
    </div>
    <div class="title_grid inside_text" style="width: 160px;">
     <span>&nbsp;Acura Advanced</span>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a margin of 5px around each image, you get rid of all margins. It should work with a margin of 5px, 20px, which ever value I throw at it.

Comment: why not wrap the code posted above in div tags and put margin on them?

Comment: If there is no simpler solution I guess that will have to do!

Comment: ohh yeah, you need to set display:inline-block for the wrapping div so it is as small as possible during the scale